# S3: Modify default argument before calling NextMethod()

Tags: r, oop, generics, parameter-passing

In an S3 generic function, I'd like to modify a function argument before calling `NextMethod()`. As a starting point, I looked through [#44](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/Wishlist-for-R/issues/44) of Henrik Bengtsson's "Wishlist for R". The following snippet is taken from there and corresponds to his suggestion on to how modify an argument before calling `NextMethod()`.

```r
x <- structure(NA, class = "A")
expected <- list(x = x, a = 3)

foo <- function(x, a) UseMethod("foo")

foo.A <- function(x, a) {
  a <- a + 1
  NextMethod()
}

foo.default <- function(x, a) {
  list(x = x, a = a)
}

identical(foo(x, a = 2), expected)
#> [1] TRUE
identical(foo(x, 2), expected)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Now what has me stumped is the following behavior where the argument to be modified has a default value.

```r
bar <- function(x, a) UseMethod("bar")

bar.A <- function(x, a = 2) {
  a <- a + 1
  NextMethod()
}

bar.default <- function(x, a = 2) {
  list(x = x, a = a)
}

identical(bar(x, a = 2), expected)
#> [1] TRUE
identical(bar(x, 2), expected)
#> [1] TRUE
identical(bar(x), expected)
#> [1] FALSE
```

Can someone help me understand what is happening here? Any ideas on how to make the default argument case work (apart from an explicit call of `bar.default()`)?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how realistic this set-up is, but the problem with it is that calling `bar(x)` means that you are calling `bar.A(x)`, then (via `NextMethod()`) you are calling `bar.default(x)`, rather than `bar.default(x, a = 3)` as you might expect.

The way round this is to specifically pass `a` as a parameter in `NextMethod`. The issue you will have with this is that if the user doesn't name the second parameter, then `bar.default` will throw because it is being given 3 parameters instead of two (`x`, `2` and `a = 3`). You can get round this by including a `...` parameter in `bar.default` so that unnamed parameters are ignored.

```r
x <- structure(NA, class = "A")
expected <- list(x = x, a = 3)

bar <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("bar")

bar.A <- function(x, a = 2) {
  a <- a + 1
  NextMethod("bar", x, a = a)
}

bar.default <- function(x, ..., a = 2) {
  list(x = x, a = a)
}

identical(bar(x, a = 2), expected)
#> [1] TRUE
identical(bar(x, 2), expected)
#> [1] TRUE
identical(bar(x), expected)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>